# MIPS: How can I do the sum?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to do an assembly program where it is asked to do a routine that has as an input parameter address a stringC , return the BCD sum (two digits per byte) of the elements of the string , also assumed to BCD . I started by doing the following:

```
    .data
message1 : .asciiz 
message2 : .asciiz 
userinput : .space 100

.text

main:   
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, message1
    syscall

    #Getting user's input as text
    li $v0,8
    la $a0,userinput
    li $a1,100
    syscall

    #Display string
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,userinput
    syscall

    # jal sumelements

    #Tell the system this is the end of main
    li $v0,10
    syscall

sumelements:


    #Display sum
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,message2
    syscall


    #Tell the system this is the end of main
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Can someone help me ? Am I going in the right way ? I have no idea how will I do the part of the sum.

Comment: Are you sure about BCD? For a number 1234, when you prompt user for string the way you're doing it, the string will be ascii: `.byte 0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34` but the BCD would be: `.byte 0x12,0x34`. If you prompt/read this way, you'll have to convert ascii to BCD. Can you predefine the BCD (e.g. `bcd1: .byte 0x12,0x34` and `bcd2: .byte 0x56,0x78` to produce `sum: .byte 0x69,0x12`)? I'd edit your question to clarify this. And, I might write this in C first [and you could also post that]

Comment: What you mean by "Are you sure about BCD?" Can you clarify that...

Comment: Try reading the whole comment. Your code gets ascii and not BCD. So, you'd have to convert. Is that what you intend to do? Do you have to prompt or can you predefine the BCD numbers with `.byte` directives? And is your BCD going to be big-endian or little-endian oriented? And, can you have variable sized BCD numbers with [say] bcd1 with 4 digits, but bcd2 has 7?